# Is my observation correct regarding restriction of scalars?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $\alpha: \Lambda\to \Gamma$ be a ring homomorphism, then $ _\Lambda\Gamma_\Gamma$ is a bimodule. We have the following pairs of adjoint functors
$$
\mathbf{Mod_\Lambda}  \xrightarrow{\cdot\; \otimes_\Lambda \Gamma}   \mathbf{Mod_\Gamma} \xrightarrow{\operatorname{Hom}_\Gamma(\Gamma,\;\cdot\;)} \mathbf{Mod_\Lambda},
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{Mod_\Lambda}  \xrightarrow{\cdot\; \otimes_\Lambda \Gamma}   \mathbf{Mod_\Gamma} \xrightarrow{\;\cdot\;_\Lambda}  \mathbf{Mod_\Lambda},
$$
as well as
$$
\mathbf{Mod_\Gamma}   \xrightarrow{\;\cdot\;_\Lambda}   \mathbf{Mod_\Lambda}  \xrightarrow{\operatorname{Hom}_\Lambda(\Gamma,\;\cdot\;)}  \mathbf{Mod_\Gamma}.
$$

Then $\operatorname{Hom}_\Gamma(\Gamma,\;\cdot\;)$ is naturally isomorphic to $\;\cdot\;_\Lambda$ and thus is left-adjoint to $\operatorname{Hom}_\Lambda(\Gamma,\;\cdot\;)$.

Is all this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.